# why my query doesn't work correctly?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ef-database-first

hi i used this query for update my db but not working :

```
if (Request["mode"] != null)
        {
            Int32 ID = Int32.Parse(Request["Id"].ToString());
            using (NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1 dbContext = new NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1())
            {
                var ToEdit = (from n in dbContext.Packages
                                  where n.Id == ID
                                  select n).FirstOrDefault();
                ToEdit.Name = txtName.Text;
                ToEdit.Level = txtLevel.Text;
                ToEdit.Description = txtDescription.Text;
                ToEdit.ForAge = ddlAgeFor.SelectedItem.Text;
                ToEdit.CatId = ddlCategory.SelectedIndex + 1;
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                //Response.Redirect("Packages.aspx");
                //return;*/
            }
        }
```

Comment: define not working, does it error?

Comment: @Luke McGregor it'not any error.

Comment: Here's my advice: Provide more info about the problem. Or perhaps, collect more info before posting.

Comment: I cant see an issue with the code as such, so your best bet would be to check the connection to the database itself. Make sure your connection string is correct and prehaps take a look at whats going on with EFProfiler

Comment: @Luke McGregor my Database Connection String is Correct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved my problem,i was forgotten that i use the IsPostBack :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request["Id"] != null)
            {
                Int32 ID = Int32.Parse(Request["Id"].ToString());
                using (NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1 dbContext = new NoavaranModel.NoavaranEntities1())
                {
                    var query = (from list in dbContext.Packages
                                 where list.Id == ID
                                 select list).FirstOrDefault();
                    txtName.Text = query.Name;
                    txtLevel.Text = query.Level;
                    txtDescription.Text = query.Description;
                    Image2.ImageUrl = "PackageImages/" + query.Image;
                    ddlAgeFor.Text = query.ForAge;
                    //ddlCategory.Text = query.CatId.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: so you didn't even posted the actual code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave` parameter to `SaveChanges()`:

```
dbContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
```

Comment: This is only needed if you are doing something already crazy (like turning off change tracking)